# boost spirit and related parts

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I need to create a rule via boost spirit that should match situations like

```
return foo;
```

and

```
return (foo);
```

I tried smth like this:

```
start %= "return" >> -boost::spirit::qi::char_('(') >> identifier >> -boost::spirit::qi::char_(')') >> ';';
```

but this will succeeded even in cases like

```
return (foo;
```

and

```
return foo);
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What about `statement = ("return" >> identifier >> ';') | ("return" >> '(' >> identifier >> ')' >> ';')`?

Comment: @faranwath Yep, I already thought about it, but it looks horrible, especially in case when I have a lot of rules with the similar structure

Comment: Horrible? I guess we differ in what makes a production rule look nice, but it's your work, so fair enough.

Comment: Since you seem to have many of those rules, you could use the relevant parser (here identifier) as an argument to a parser handling the parenthesis. However, parsers as arguments to parsers have some problems, there is a nice post here on SO by sehe but I cannot find it right away.

Comment: Also I need to have the same amount of open and close parentheses and I could even have two or more parentheses pairs in one expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example only looks pathological, because you are using an overly specific example.

In practice, you don't `"return" >> identifier;`. Usually, the thing that's returned is just an expression. So, you'd say

```
expr = literal | variable | function_call;
```

Now the general way to cater for parenthesized expressions in on fell swoop is simply:

```
expr = literal | variable | function_call
     | ('(' >> expr >> ')')
     ;
```

Bam. Done. It handles the balancing. It handles nested parentheses. It handles `(((foo)))` even. Not a *whistle* was given that day.

I don't think there is /anything/ wrong at all. I've posted probably over 20 recursive different expression grammars in answers on this site. They should provide motivating examples (showing operator precedence and overruling them with these parentheses).

Comment: Can you give me an idea why does the following code crash with "stack overflow" error? http://pastie.org/8732392 Input data - http://pastie.org/8732447 I guess that it's a result of adding recursion in my rules. Am I right? How can I fix it?

Comment: Left recursion and PEG grammars :) they don't mix

Comment: Can you rephrase, please? What should I do in case of boost spirit?

Comment: This was just to fix the compilation issues (rules shadowing type names): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25bbfd4abfc719f1

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm using MSVC-11.0 and boost 1.54 and it doesn't give me any errors at all. Can you answer my question about recursion in rules and stack overflow, please?

Comment: Can you post it as a proper question please? (I have the answer sitting here, but since you seem to be in a hurry...)

Comment: Ok, done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773660/boost-spirit-recursion-and-stack-overflow